# C# TcpListener. Как определить момент отключения клиента?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, tcplistener

Есть BackgroundService, который запускает прослушивание tcp-порта. Код сервиса:

```
public sealed class TcpListenerWrapper : ITcpListenerWrapper
{
    private readonly TcpListener _listener;
    private readonly IMessageManager _messageManager;

    public TcpListenerWrapper(ITcpListenerWrapperConfiguration config, IMessageManager messageManager)
    {
        _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, config.PortNumber);
        _messageManager = messageManager;
    }

    public async Task StartListeningAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _listener.Start();

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var client = await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("A new client connected!");

            _ = Task.Run(() => ProcessClientAsync(client, stoppingToken), stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessClientAsync(TcpClient client, CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var stream = client.GetStream();

        while (client.Connected && !stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var packet = await ReceiveFixedPacketAsync(stream, stoppingToken);

            var messageAsText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(packet);
            Console.WriteLine($"New message received: {messageAsText}");

            var message = _messageManager.CreateMessage(packet);
            await message.SaveAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Saving ends");
        }

        var info = !client.Connected
            ? "Remote client disconnected. Client message processing ends"
            : "Service shutting down. Disconnecting...";

        Console.WriteLine(info);
        client.Close();
    }

    private static async Task<byte[]> ReceiveFixedPacketAsync(Stream stream, CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[SuntechProtocolInfo.MaxFullPacketLength];
        int bytesRead;
        do
        {
            bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, stoppingToken);
        } while (bytesRead <= 0);

        return buffer;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _listener.Stop();
    }
}
```

Ожидается, что в методе `ProcessClientAsync` после отключения клиента выполнится выход из цикла по условию `client.Connected`, но этого не происходит.

В качестве теста сделал себе еще 2 BackgroundService, которые отправляют данные слушателю. Код клиентов ниже:

BackgroundTcpSenderBase.cs

```
public abstract class BackgroundTcpSenderBase : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly TcpClient _client;
    private int _messageCounter = 0;
    protected abstract string DeviceName { get; }
    protected virtual double SendPeriodInMinutes { get; set; } = 1;

    protected BackgroundTcpSenderBase(ILogger logger)
    {
        _client = new TcpClient();
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        const int portNumber = 9000;
        var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), portNumber);

        _client.Connect(endPoint);

        var timer = new Timer(e =>
        {
            SendPackage();
        }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(SendPeriodInMinutes));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        _client.GetStream().Close();
        _client.Close();
        base.Dispose();
    }

    private void SendPackage()
    {
        var stream = _client.GetStream();
        var message = $"Device {DeviceName} sends message #{++_messageCounter}";
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

BackgroundTcpSender1.cs

```
public class BackgroundTcpSender1 : BackgroundTcpSenderBase
{
    protected override string DeviceName { get; } = "Sender_1";

    public BackgroundTcpSender1(ILogger<BackgroundTcpSender1> logger) : base(logger)
    {
    }
}
```

BackgroundTcpSender2.cs

```
public class BackgroundTcpSender2 : BackgroundTcpSenderBase
{
    protected override string DeviceName { get; } = "Sender_2";
    protected override double SendPeriodInMinutes { get; set; } = 0.5;

    public BackgroundTcpSender2(ILogger<BackgroundTcpSender2> logger) : base(logger)
    {
    }
}
```

В дебаге выяснил, что при отключении клиента поток зависает в цикле метода ReceiveFixedPacketAsync:

```
    do
    {
        bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, stoppingToken);
    } while (bytesRead <= 0);
```

При этом Socket у переменной `stream` все еще доступен. Не могу понять, почему так.

**Вопрос:** как отловить момент отключения TCP-клиента?

**UPD.** Нашел ответ на англоязычном StackOverflow [ссылка на оригинальный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2661764/6468198). Однако меня смущает параметр `microseconds` в функции [`Socket.Poll`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.poll?view=netcore-3.1). К примеру, я выставлю 1000 микросекунд ожидание ответа. На localhost это прекрасно работает. Но что, если подключится удаленный клиент? И соединение с ним медленное. Не посчитает ли функция `SocketConnected`, что мой сокет отключился?

Comment: поставьте 10 секунд. Это Ваше приложение и только Вы знаете, какой таймаут есть правильным.

Comment: @KoVadim да, можно. Однако этот метод будет замораживать обработку сообщений на 10 секунд, если каждый раз перед чтением вызывать Poll. Пока думаю, как лучше его применить таким образом, чтобы проверка соединения была в фоновом потоке, и если разорвалось соединение, то прервать цикл обработки сообщений

Comment: если есть новые данные - они сразу прибегут. Если нет - только только ждать. Так что в общем случае все работает как надо.

Comment: @KoVadim я тоже так думал, но, к сожалению, независимо от того, пришел ответ или нет, он в любом случае заморозит выполнение на то количество микросекунд, которое передается параметром (проверил практическим путем)

Comment: А может Вы Poll неверно вызываете?

Comment: @KoVadim вызываю так (http://pastie.org/p/3VCXphbIxlx7LeALFZsTcV). Зависает на 10 секунд после выполнения Poll

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112869/discussion-between-andrei-khotko-and-kovadim).

Comment: я понял. Вы проверяете таким образом, жив ли сокет. А на самом деле код проверяет, пришли ли данные. Подобным кодом невозможно проверить, жив ли сокет. Единственный способ проверить, жив ли сокет - послать данные и дождаться ожидаемого ответа.

Comment: @KoVadim а как же стандартные пакеты с флагами `FIN` или `RST` на завершение соединения? Неужели .NET не может их отследить и сказать `клиент разорвал соединение`? Вот, например, как выглядит трафик через порт 9000. При завершении соединения клиент отправил [FIN, ASK]. [Скриншот](http://joxi.ru/MAjkXzVUxeO5xr)

Comment: Завершения соединения он должен перехватывать.

Comment: @KoVadim как именно он это делает? Меняет свойство `Client.Connected`?

Comment: вот этого я уже не знаю

Comment: @KoVadim Если вдруг вам интересно: протестировал соединение удаленного клиента (до которого пинг > 40 ms) c методом Poll с 1 миллисекундой - соединение не падает. В общем, Poll с маленькой задержкой работает как надо.

Answer (score -1):

Решал данную задачу через Poll

в цикле, где слушаете сообщения:

```
            if (tcpClient.Client.Poll(1000000, SelectMode.SelectRead)) // произошло изменение на сокете
            {
                if (tcpClient.GetStream().DataAvailable) // Есть какие-то данные
                {
                    // обработка запроса
                }
                else // Если нет, то произошел обрыв связи
                {
                    // обработка отключения
                }
             }
```